# Google App Engine DeobfuscatorBuilder

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm trying build an App Engine connected Android application and am having some problems using the RequestFactory.  In particular I noticed that the DeobfuscatorBuilder is appending an "L" to the beginning of my paths for some reason. Here are my logs:

```
03-24 14:56:44.789: I/dalvikvm(382): Failed resolving Lcsc440/nuf/shared/SMILMessageProxy;     interface 77 'Lcom/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/ValueProxy;'
03-24 14:56:44.789: W/dalvikvm(382): Link of class 'Lcsc440/nuf/shared/SMILMessageProxy;' failed
03-24 14:56:44.789: W/dalvikvm(382): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature   (Lcsc440/nuf/shared/SMILMessageProxy;)
```

I've traced the source to Google's GWT SDK in the class -
**com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.DescriptorBuilder**

containing the following method:

```
@Override
  public String visitDeclared(DeclaredType x, State state) {
    return "L"
        + BinaryName.toInternalName(state.elements.getBinaryName((TypeElement) x.asElement())
        .toString()) + ";";
 }
```

This seems wrong to me but I'm a novice, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class name starting with L is used in JNI to access Java classes from C code - `"Ljava/lang/String"` refers to the class `java.lang.String` [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface#Mapping_types)

The error you get is therefore in native code that does not find a class in `csc440.nuf.shared.SMILMessageProxy`